# How do I echo more than one product dynamically on the same invoice page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo more than one item on an invoice for the same customer. I am able to echo them from the database, but instead of each item being echoed on the same invoice (on different rows), it echoes the full invoice 2 times (or more depending on how many items are on the invoice) with each item on each invoice. Below is my code (I have not yet cleaned the code up. I am leaving that step once the code works).

```
<?php include "database_connection.php" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>DPB quote</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"><!--erase this link once the app is completed-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style2.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media="print" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/example.js'></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"><!--search pagination and delete reference link-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><!--search pagination and delete reference link-->

  </head>
  <body>



<?php
$statement = $connect->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM tbl_order
    WHERE order_id = :order_id
    LIMIT 1
");
$statement->execute(
  array(
    ':order_id'       =>  $_GET["id"]
    )
  );
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#order_no').val("<?php echo $row["order_no"]; ?>");
  $('#order_date').val("<?php echo $row["order_date"]; ?>");
  $('#order_receiver_name').val("<?php echo $row["order_receiver_name"]; ?>");
  $('#address_line_1').val("<?php echo $row["address_line_1"]; ?>");
  $('#address_line_2').val("<?php echo $row["address_line_2"]; ?>");
  $('#city').val("<?php echo $row["city"]; ?>");
  $('#state').val("<?php echo $row["state"]; ?>");
  $('#zip_code').val("<?php echo $row["zip_code"]; ?>");
  $('#phone_number').val("<?php echo $row["phone_number"]; ?>");
  $('#email').val("<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>");
  $('#notes').val("<?php echo $row["notes"]; ?>");
});
</script>

<form method="post" id="invoice_form">
<div class="container">

<?php
$statement = $connect->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM tbl_order_item
  WHERE order_id = :order_id
");
$statement->execute(
  array(
    ':order_id'       =>  $_GET["id"]
  )
);
$item_result = $statement->fetchAll();
$m = 0;
foreach($item_result as $sub_row)
{
  $m = $m + 1;
?>

<!--QUOTATION APP 2 STARTS HERE-->

<div id="page-wrap">

  <textarea id="header">Quotation</textarea>

  <div id="identity">

          <textarea id="address">Discount Plastic Bags
7750
Suite
Irving
Phone: </textarea>

          <div id="logo">



            <div id="logohelp">

              (max width: 540px, max height: 300px)
            </div>
            <img id="image" src="images/dpblogo3.png" alt="logo" />
          </div>

  </div>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <div id="customer">

<!--<form id="quote_date" class="" action="index.php" method="post">-->

              <tr>
                <td><textarea placeholder="Enter Customer Information" id="address" name="company_info"></textarea></td>
              </tr>

          <table id="meta">
              <tr>
                  <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                  <td><textarea>000123</textarea></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
                  <td><textarea placeholder="enter quotation date" name="quote_date"></textarea></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
                  <td><textarea placeholder="enter amount due" name="amount_due"></textarea></td>
              </tr>

          </table>




        </div>

        <table id="items">

          <tr>
              <th>SKU</th>
              <th>Description</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Unit Cost</th>
              <th>Price</th>
          </tr>

          <tr class="item-row">
          <!--<td><span id="sr_no"><?php //echo $m; ?></span></td>-->

              <td><input type="text" name="sku[]" id="sku<?php echo $m; ?>" class="item-name" value="<?php echo $sub_row["sku"]; ?>" /></td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name<?php echo $m; ?>" class="description" value="<?php echo $sub_row["item_name"]; ?>" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity<?php echo $m; ?>" data-srno="<?php echo $m; ?>" class="qty" value = "<?php echo $sub_row["order_item_quantity"]; ?>" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price<?php echo $m; ?>" data-srno="<?php echo $m; ?>" class="cost" value="<?php echo $sub_row["order_item_price"]; ?>" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount<?php echo $m; ?>" data-srno="<?php echo $m; ?>" readonly class="price" value="<?php echo $sub_row["order_item_final_amount"]; ?>" /></td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"></td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="subtotal" name="subtotal"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

              <td colspan="2" class="blank"></td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
              <td class="total-value"><textarea name="total" id="total"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
              <td class="total-value balance"><textarea name="balance_due" class="due"> </textarea></td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <div id="terms">
          <h5>Notes</h5>
          <textarea name="notes" placeholder="enter quotation notes" rows="12" style="font-size: 15pt"></textarea>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>


<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: just place the parts of the screen that have more than one value into the loop.

Comment: Hi briskovich. Thanks for the reply. All the items that have more than one value are inside the loop. Maybe I am missing your point. Would you be so kind as to show me how (or where) the code has to be edited, please.

Comment: I posted an answer with how I do what you are trying to do. Stuff with one value is outside the loop, stuff with multiple values are inside the loop. If you have an invoice some of the stuff will be one for one. Whatever isn't put that inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. This is not tested and just an example of how I do it. There are a few other ways but this works best for me

```
// other needed code above 
    $results = sqlsrv_query($link, $query);
    //query returns one value for these       
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>  ";
echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
echo "<td>".$store."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
//start your multiple items row     
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))
       {
                $items = $row['items']; 
                echo "<tr>  ";
                echo "<td>".$items."</td> ";
                echo "</tr>";
       }
echo "<tr>  ";     
echo "<td>".$cost."</td>";
echo "<td>".$other."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>  ";
//other code for the rest of the page below
```

Result would be:

```
Bob  Bob's Store    
ITEM 
ITEM 
ITEM
$50.00 other
```

Comment: Hi briskovich, Thanks again for the guide, but I do need the code that I posted to work instead of using a different approach.

Comment: It would have to be modified to suit your specific need but this is the gist of how I do it.

Comment: Thanks briskovich, I am still trying to figure out what to modify on my code to make it work correctly. I'm crossing my fingers in hope to get more feedback. :)

Comment: I got it to work perfectly. Looks like I did not place the parts that had more than one in the loop as "briskovich" said.

Comment: Hi briskovich. I want to accept your answer, but I do not know where I should accept it as answered. I am new to stack overflow, so I do not know where all the options are for accepting and placing the question as answered, etc. If you will be so kind as to tell me where and how to accept your answer, I will do so. Thanks :)

Comment: You should be able to just select it as your answer. I haven't asked a question in some time.